# Opengl triangle gets color of the first vertex

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

So I was trying out some opengl code the other day. Here's my code.
Main:

```
#include <glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>

#include "Mesh.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
glfwInit();

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "HGLW", NULL, NULL);
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
int succes = glewInit();
if (succes != GLEW_OK){
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    glfwTerminate();
}
glEnable(GL_DEPTH);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

Mesh mesh();

mesh.setShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "Shaders/Shader.vert");
mesh.setShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "Shaders/Shader.frag");
mesh.linkShaders();

mesh.upload();

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
    glfwPollEvents();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    mesh.render();

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}

return 0;
```

}

relevant Mesh functions:

```
Mesh::Mesh(){
//generate the vertex and index buffers
glGenBuffers(1, &_vbo);
glGenBuffers(1, &_ibo);

//generating the vertex array
glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vao);

//link the right buffers to the vao
glBindVertexArray(_vao);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _ibo);

glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void Mesh::upload()
{

std::vector<GLfloat> verts = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                               1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                               -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
_indices = { 0, 1, 2};

glBindVertexArray(_vao);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(sizeof(GLfloat)*3));

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*verts.size(), &verts[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLushort)*_indices.size(),     &_indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void Mesh::render(){
//if the program exists, use it
if (_program != NULL){
    glUseProgram(_program);
}

glBindVertexArray(_vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(NULL);
}
```

vertex shader:

```
#version 430

layout(location=0) in vec3 position;
layout(location=1) in vec3 inColor;

out vec3 outColor;

void main(){

gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0f);

outColor = inColor;

}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 430

in vec3 outColor;

out vec4 color;

void main(){

color = vec4(outColor, 1.0f);
```

}

What I get is not a red, green and blue triangle, but a entirely red one. and when I change the first color (the fourth, fifth and sixth element of verts) to green, my entire triangle becomes green. So it looks like my entire triangle has the first specified color instead of all 3.

Is there anyone who knows whats going on here? I've made these types of programs before and they all worked fine; I just can't find any real differences between my working programs and this one.

I'm using opengl 4.5

Comment: I don't think you want to use a stride of `6 * sizeof(GLfloat)`, you can use `0` as the default or specify as `3 * sizeof(GLfloat)`, since your position and color are both 3 float-elements each.

Comment: @cehnehdeh Stride is the space between each vertex attribute block's start, which is 6 floats here. 0 is invalid since he is interleaving the color and position. 0 is only allowed as a substitute for a number if the attribute is contained in blocks of only that attribute. In interleaving, the stride should be the size of each vertex.

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like flat shading model. Is it solved by setting shade model to smooth calling 'glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)' during init?

Comment: maybe. I can't test it now, because I already rewrote everything and now it's working again.

Comment: @Andreas I would think applying a fragment shader would override that, but then I haven't programmed any OpenGL with/using fixed function. OP, what version is this binding? That might be relevant information.

Comment: @WilliamKappler Yeah you are right. There is no way for OpenGL to know which attribute is color unless using the built-in attributes and varyings.